# VS Emulator for Android - Failed to load assembly Java.Interop

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android

Trying to debug the Android Image Search demo in VS2015 Update 3 but get the following errors. Verified Android 6.0 SDK is installed and have latest Xamarin for VS updates (4.2.680).

https://github.com/xamarin/dev-days-labs/tree/master/Demos/app-imagesearch-cogs

> 09-25 14:44:49.924 D/Mono    ( 1413): Image addref
>   Mono.Android[0xae5144c0] -> Mono.Android.dll[0xaaea0f00]: 1 09-25
>   14:44:49.924 D/Mono    ( 1413): Assembly Mono.Android[0xae5144c0]
>   added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1 09-25 14:44:49.924 D/Mono    (
>   1413): AOT module 'Mono.Android.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library
>   "/data/app/ImageSearch.Droid.ImageSearch.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-Mono.Android.dll.so"
>   not found 09-25 14:44:49.925 D/Mono    ( 1413): AOT module
>   '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/f4db8a57/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Mono.Android.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/ImageSearch.Droid.ImageSearch.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-Mono.Android.dll.so"
>   not found 09-25 14:44:49.960 D/Mono    ( 1413): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'Mono.Android.dll.config'. 09-25 14:44:49.960 D/Mono    (
>   1413): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/f4db8a57/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Android/Mono.Android.config'.
>   09-25 14:44:49.964 D/Mono    ( 1413): Assembly Ref addref
>   Mono.Android[0xae5144c0] -> mscorlib[0xae512360]: 2 09-25 14:44:49.965
>   D/Mono    ( 1413): Image addref Java.Interop[0xae514580] ->
>   Java.Interop.dll[0xaaea1400]: 1 09-25 14:44:49.965 D/Mono    ( 1413):
>   Assembly Java.Interop[0xae514580] added to domain RootDomain,
>   ref_count=1 09-25 14:44:49.966 D/Mono    ( 1413): AOT module
>   'Java.Interop.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/ImageSearch.Droid.ImageSearch.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-Java.Interop.dll.so"
>   not found 09-25 14:44:49.966 D/Mono    ( 1413): AOT module
>   '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/f4db8a57/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Java.Interop.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/ImageSearch.Droid.ImageSearch.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-Java.Interop.dll.so"
>   not found 09-25 14:44:49.966 D/Mono    ( 1413): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'Java.Interop.dll.config'. 09-25 14:44:49.966 D/Mono    (
>   1413): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/f4db8a57/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/Java.Interop/Java.Interop.config'.
>   09-25 14:44:49.966 D/Mono    ( 1413): Assembly Ref addref
>   System.Runtime[0xae513320] -> mscorlib[0xae512360]: 3 09-25
>   14:44:49.966 W/Mono    ( 1413): The following reference assembly
>   assembly referenced from Java.Interop.dll was not loaded.  Reference
>   assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be
>   loaded in the Reflection-only loader context: 09-25 14:44:49.966
>   W/Mono    ( 1413):      Assembly:   System.Runtime   
>   (assemblyref_index=1) 09-25 14:44:49.966 W/Mono    ( 1413):     
>   Version:    4.0.0.0 09-25 14:44:49.966 W/Mono    ( 1413):      Public
>   Key: b03f5f7f11d50a3a 09-25 14:44:49.966 D/Mono    ( 1413): Failed to
>   load assembly Java.Interop[0xae514580] 09-25 14:44:49.966 W/        (
>   1413): Can't find custom attr constructor image: Java.Interop.dll
>   mtoken: 0x0a0000a2 due to Could not load file or assembly or one of
>   its dependencies. assembly:System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:
>   member: 09-25 14:44:49.966 D/Mono    ( 1413): Failed to load
>   assembly Mono.Android[0xae5144c0]

Answer (score 0):

A Xamarin update fixed this issue today.

https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-service-release-0/